# MQTT connection works in Node but not as a ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, mqtt

I have this mqtt connection that works fine when I run it in nodeJS ... but when I move it into a react component I get this error:

Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I've read this is caused by something to do with default ports here ...
[Usage of MQTT protocol in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944899/usage-of-mqtt-protocol-in-react)
but I can't find an answer I understand enough to solve it.

Can anyone help? Cheers

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import mqtt from "mqtt";

let topic = "vendingmachine2/command";
const options = {
  port: 16987,
  host: "mqtt://address.cloudmqtt.com",
  clientId: "***",
  username: "***",
  password: "***",
  keepalive: 60,
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
  protocolId: "MQIsdp",
  protocolVersion: 3,
  clean: true,
  encoding: "utf8",
  timeout: 3,
  useSSL: true
};
function CheckoutForm() {
const MQTTConnect = () => {
    const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://address.cloudmqtt.com", options);
    client.on("connect", function() {
      // When connected
      console.log("connected");
      client.subscribe("vendingmachine2/feedback", error => {
        if (error) console.error(error);
        else {
          client.publish(topic, "0");
        }
      });
      openDoor();
    });
    client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
      console.log(topic, message.toString());
    });
    function openDoor() {
      let door = [1, 2];
      for (let i = 0; i < door.length; i++) {
        client.publish(topic, `${door[i]}`);
      }
    }
};
return (
    <div>

        <button onClick={MQTTConnect}>asdasd</button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default CheckoutForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to force a native MQTT connection using the `mqtt://` schema for the broker URL.

The problem is when the ReactJS code runs in the browser it can't use native MQTT (because of the browser sandbox), you need to use MQTT over Websockets.

You do this by changing the URL schema to `wss://` (MQTT over Secure Websockets) and change the port number. The Cloudmqtt [docs](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs/websocket.html) say the port will be `36987` rather than `16987`.

You should be able to use MQTT over Websockets from NodeJS as well as ReactJS.

Answer (score 2):

the URL schema is to be changed to `wss://` for it to work and the port has to be changed to the websocket's port instead of the instance's port

Answer (score 2):

working solution

install **precompiled-mqtt** npm package

```
import mqtt from "precompiled-mqtt";

const URL = "ws://x.xxx.xx.xxx:8000";
  const [client, setClient] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    mqttConnect();
  }, []);


const mqttConnect = () => {
    const client = mqtt.connect(URL, {
      // clientId: "mqttjs_" + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      hostname: "x.xxx.xx.xxx",
      port: 8000,
      path: "/mqtt",
    });
    setClient(client);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (client) {
      client.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected");
        setConnectStatus("Connected");
      });
      client.on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("Connection error: ", err);
        client.end();
      });
      client.on("reconnect", () => {
        setConnectStatus("Reconnecting");
      });
      client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
        const payload = { topic, message: message.toString() };
        console.log("payload", payload);
      });
    }
  }, [client]);
```

Answer (score 1):

mainak is right. the solution worked. but please dont forget to sub topic.

```
  client.on("reconnect", () => {
    setConnectStatus("Reconnecting");
  });
client.subscribe(`ChannelName`, () => {                        // 'car', 'car/' , 'chatIst' ...
        
        client.on("message", (topic, message, packet) => {
          console.log("message:", JSON.parse(message));
          
        });
      });
```